# Why does my hashing program fail the tests

Tags: c++, string, hash, char

Task:
To register in the system, each resident must come up with a password. The password consists of letters of the Latin alphabet (uppercase and lowercase), as well as numbers from 0 to 9, that is, it is possible to use 62 characters in total. The password length is from 5 to 20 characters. The password is stored in the database in encrypted form, encryption is carried out according to the following algorithm:

1. The number b of uppercase Latin letters is counted. For each uppercase letter character in the password, a cyclic shift to the right by bb characters is performed (for example, if b=3, then the D character is converted to the G character, the Y character to the B character).
2. Similarly, for each lowercase character in the password, a cyclic shift to the right is performed by m characters, where m is the number of lowercase letters in the password.

To quickly search for users in the database, a hash function is calculated for each encrypted password using the following algorithm:

1. All 62 characters are ordered, numbers come first, then lowercase letters, then uppercase letters.
2. Each character is assigned a code - the number of the character in this sequence, starting from 0. Thus, the digit codes match their values, the lowercase letter code a-10, b-11, etc.
3. All codes are summed up, and the remainder of the resulting sum s is found from dividing by the numbers p and q. The resulting pair of numbers (s mod p,s mod q) will be the value of the hash function.

A hash function is considered good if collisions rarely occur, that is, the values of the function match for different passwords.

John came up with a new password. At the same time, there are already nn passwords in the database, and I would like to avoid collisions. Will John succeed?

Input data

The first line contains a string representing John's password.
The second line contains an integer n – the number of passwords in the database.
The third line contains integers p and q. The following lines store passwords in unencrypted form.

Output data

An integer is the number of passwords whose hash function matches the hash function of John's password.

Sample Input:
AabB1cd
5
13 17
Nik143pasw
**qeAom1**
q1w2e3r4t
aBoba2012
**N33iEj**

Sample Output:
2

Note:
Passwords that match John's hash function are highlighted.

Processing of John's password:
After cyclic shift: CefD1gh (uppercase letters are shifted by 2, lowercase by 4)
The sum of the character codes is 38+14+15+39+1+16+17=140
The hash function is equal to (10,4)

Comment: What are the inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs of your five tests? There is a LOT of info here. If you could only show the parts that are causing the problem, that would be helpful. Please reed [example].

Comment: Code will fail with the unlikely possibility of a system that uses  EBCDIC encoding. If you're coding for an old IBM mainframe, watch out.

Comment: Avoid magic numbers `hash = hash + (pas[i] - 48);` instead of - 48 you should use '0' so:  `hash = hash + (pas[i] - '0');`

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger? The best solution is to run your debugger to key points in the program and compare the current state of the program (values of the variables) to their expected values. Once you find the actual does not equal the expected, you can be sure that the error occurred at the previous step.

Comment: Please have mercy for any reader (others or you) and do not write whole code in `main` function. Split code into multiple functions separating concerns: reading data, printing result, calculating hash, finding collisions. The faster you will learn to split code then better.

Comment: Have you learned how to make functions yet? There are several utility functions you could write that would simplify the main body of your code. You repeat a lot of different code statements a lot, and putting the functionality in named functions reduces the cognitive load you need to reason about your program. If you make a `is_upper(char c)` function, and you test that it works, you can be sure it will always work. You don't need to worry about `(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` being fat-fingered in a hard-to-find-spot. Functions also make it easier for reviewers (me) to read.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tried adding functions, thanks for helping me improve my programming skills.

Comment: Write a test program that uses your `rotate` functions with test input. Do you get the values you expect?

Comment: Better yet, use your debugger and set breakpoints at those functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to come up with tests and experiment with the debugger. If I come to a dead end, I will write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few logic problems in your code. When you are rotating your upper and lower-case characters to their "encrypted" forms, you iterate through the password twice, and sometimes incorrectly rotate the characters. Take for example just the line

```
if (pas[i] + big >= 'A' && pas[i] + big <= 'Z') pas[i] = pas[i] + big;
```

Consider the case where `pas[i] == '9'` and `big == 8`. You will end up transforming all of your `9`'s into `A`s.

Now consider the line in the next loop

```
if (pas[i] + small >= 'a' && pas[i] + small <= 'z') pas[i] = pas[i] + small;
```

Which will similarly transform some upper-case letters into lower-case if `small` is large enough.

You can also combine these two problems. Consider the case where `pas[i]` is originally `Y`, `big` is 1, `little` is 7. You'll transform `Y --> Z`, and then in the next step transform `Z --> a`.

1. Compartmentalize and abstract your single large main function into smaller functional blocks. This will allow you to reason about each piece individually instead of trying to keep the entirely of `main()` in your head. Humans have limited short-term memory.

Some suggested functions would include

- `bool is_upper(char c)`
- `bool is_lower(char c)`
- `bool is_numeric(char c)`
- `char rotate_upper(char c, int steps)`
- `char rotate_lower(char c, int steps)`

2. Instead of looping through the password twice on your transformation step, consider looping through the password once. If the character is upper-case, transform accordingly. If it's lower-case, transform accordingly. This will prevent you from double-rotating some numbers.

Combining all of the above, the two encryption loops of your main function could turn from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pas.length(); i++)
    {
        if (pas[i] + big >= 'A' && pas[i] + big <= 'Z') pas[i] = pas[i] + big;
        else if (pas[i] >= 'A' && pas[i] <= 'Z') {
            int tempVar = big;
            while (tempVar > 0) {
                if (pas[i] == 'Z') {
                    pas[i] = 'A';
                    tempVar = tempVar - 1;
                }
                tempVar = tempVar - 1;
                pas[i] = pas[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pas.length(); i++)
    {
        if (pas[i] + small >= 'a' && pas[i] + small <= 'z') pas[i] = pas[i] + small;
        else if (pas[i] >= 'a' && pas[i] <= 'z') {
            int tempVar = small;
            while (tempVar > 0) {
                if (pas[i] == 'z') {
                    pas[i] = 'a';
                    tempVar = tempVar - 1;
                }
                pas[i] = pas[i] + 1;
                tempVar = tempVar - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < pas.length(); i++) {
    char c = pas[i];
    if (is_upper(c)) {
        pas[i] = rotate_upper(c, big);
    }
    else if (is_lower(c)) {
        pas[i] = rotate_lower(c, small);
    }
}
```

You can transform 30 lines of code into just under 10. That's much easier to read for both you, the developer, and for any potential reviewers.